# Reading WIRELESS .pcap packet using Java

Tags: java, wireless, pcap, libpcap, jnetpcap

I want to read captured (.pcap) WIRELESS packets and get information like IP addresses and port number, flag ( from network layer and above layer of OSI model ). SO which JAVA library can help me. I tried with JnetPcap but did not succeed, so JnetPcap support wireless packets or not ?... or any other java library I can use for above

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jnetpcap supports wireless packets. In general, it supports all the interfaces provided by devices e.g. wlan0, eth0.

But you do not need to specify anything about wireless or wired information if you are reading packets from a pcap file, all you need to do is to use the pcap function 
 **Pcap.openOffline("path_of_pcap_file/file_name.pcap", StringBuilder errMsg)** to create the handle to read packets. 
where errMsg is a object to know any error happened while

Refer more about this function from jnetpcap documentation http://jnetpcap.com/?q=node/68

If you have done the same thing as I mentioned and still have some error, read the errMsg after the above function call.

Here to help..